# Adding custom metric in SonarQube which gets incremented whenever a function changes from the previous version of analysis

Tags: sonarqube

Is there any way to add a custom metric which gets incremented if any function changes from its previous version? So at the end of analysis this measure will tell how many functions are modified since previous version.

I have added Size metric , but it will give the measure of total functions  present and how many functions are newly added since the previous version.

[image: total functions]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Custom metrics must be updated by hand. To add a metric which is updated automatically during analysis, you'd need to write a custom plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Is there anyway to achieve the same without adding the custom metric , i mean using the predefined metrics in sonarqube which gives the count of no of functions got changed (not added newly)from previous analysis?

Comment: There is no predefined metric for this.